# Were -y- and -g- pronounced similarly in Early Middle English?

Tags: phonology, middle-english

> [[Etymonline:]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=allay&allowed_in_frame=0) Early Middle English pronunciations of -*y*- and -*g*- were not always distinct, and the word was confused in Middle English with various senses of Romanic-derived [alloy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=alloy&allowed_in_frame=0) and [allege](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=allege&allowed_in_frame=0), especially the latter in an obsolete sense of "to lighten," from Latin *ad-* "to" + *levis* (see [lever](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lever&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Because I am inexperienced with Middle English phonology, please use the [IPA](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/) if apt.

Comment: I haven't heard of that in general, outside of some words that would have been expected to have /j/ based on Old English, but that have /g/ in modern English (possibly due to Norse influence) such as "get" and "give." I think some of these words had forms with "y" in Middle English, such as "yet" and "yif." In French, there was also some confusion, which relates to your [Linguistics post about "abridge."](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14314/what-explains-the-sound-development-from-latin-vi-to-french-dg)

Comment: I believe that after a vowel, some phonological process turned some /g/s (spelled g) into /j/s (spelled y). For example, *lay* was [originally](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lay&searchmode=none) *lecgan*. and *play* was [originally](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=play&searchmode=none) *plegan*. But I don't believe this happened when /g/ and /y/ which started syllables.

Comment: @PeterShor: well, in some cases it did (like "[yellow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yellow)", OE "geolwe," related to German "gelb"). A single g in OE regularly developed to y in any position in the syllable when it was palatalized, which generally occurred before or after front vowels in the same syllable.